# Firebase Firestore Rules for Securing Accounts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on my first large firebase firestorm application. It is a essentially a multi-tenant app where we have a collection structure like:

- accounts/
- accounts/{accountID}/otherCollections

An account document looks something like this:

```
{
 "name": "ACME Inc",
 "primaryUserID": "2wUMSpffuQgcFDWWI9uHm9RY642",
 "users": {
 "2wUMSpffuQgcFDWWI9uHm9RY642": {
    "admin": true,
    "user": true
  }
 }
}
```

I want to secure the list of accounts to show only accounts that a user is authorized to see. I also want to secure the sub collections. So far I have built the following rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }    
    match /accounts/{account}{
      function signedIn() {
        return request.auth.uid != null;
      }
      function SignedInAndBelongsToAccount() {
        return signedIn() && getUser() != null;
      }
      function getRole(roleName){
        return getUser()[roleName] == true;
      }
      function getUser() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(account.uid)).data.users[request.auth.uid];
      }
     allow read: if getRole('user')
     allow write: if getRole('admin');
  }
 }
}
```

But my list is showing **all** accounts and I haven't figured out the sub collections yet. What am I missing? Does it not filter the rows, instead I would need to filter it on the app query? Or should I structure this completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first rule matches a collection and not a document, this is specifically advised against in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure):

> All match statements should point to documents, not collections.

I think that same rule is the reason you are allowed to list all documents/collections. Try removing it and see